# Autocorrelation algorithm fails in high frequencies

Tags: algorithm, audio, signal-processing, frequency, pitch

i have a problem in my guitar tuner. I'm using autocorrelation algorithm to find the sound frequency. It works almost. Problem starts in high frequencies over 300hz. Sometimes it's not sure is it 329hz or 109hz when i'm playing E4(329hz) string, subharmonic problem i think. Now i'm asking how i can eliminate those subharmonics? Any tricks?

here's my autocorrelation code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    double diff = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
        diff += Mathf.Abs (buffer [j] - buffer [i + j]);
    }

    double dx = prevDiff - diff;

    if (dx < 0 && prevDx > 0) {

        if (diff < (0.3 * maxDiff)) {

            if (sampleLen == 0) 
            {
                sampleLen = i - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    prevDx = dx;
    prevDiff = diff;
    maxDiff = Mathf.Max ((float)diff, (float)maxDiff);
}
```

Comment: I think it's not so easy to find the frequency of a sound. The autocorrelation algorithm is too naive for this task. Even if you use Fourier transform, it is sometimes difficult to distinguish between harmonics.

Comment: yes. It's very hard.. I have tried to figure this out one month now.. I tried FFT also but guess what.. I had problems with low frequencies with FFT :D Maybe i have to use both techniques somehow.

Comment: From this Wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm, it is said that "There is as yet no single ideal PDA", so you probably should content yourself with something that only works in certain situations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the standard octave uncertainty problem with respect to an unchanging pitch.  If one period is an close match to the next in a stationary signal, then N periods will also be an close match to the next N periods, thus resulting in a nearly identical autocorrelation at several submultiples of the frequency pitch and/or octaves down.  Slight changes in the amount of noise can cause one pitch submultiple to correlate better or worse than another, even though a human might not hear any difference in pitch.

To "fix" this, you have to choose one from among many nearly identical correlation peaks.  You can do this by weighting one peak candidate with the exact same autocorrelation as more likely than another peak candidate.  For instance, you can require a lower autocorrelation peak candidate to be at least x% higher than any peak representing a frequency multiple higher before you select the lower peak, where x% might be determined by experiment (e.g. how much before a human blind test panel would actually hear the lower pitch). This value likely varies with the type of musical instrument or timbre and the octave played.

Another trick is to look at the harmonic evolution of the sound, as the overtones of low notes on big strings may decay differently than the harmonics of higher strings or notes.